# How to bind events on dynamic generated buttons in backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

How do I bind click event on dynamic generated buttons in backbone.js?

```
 window.PackageView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "div",

    className: "package-template",

    events:{
      'click #display-nodes'  :  'main', // This button is declared in my HTML code and calls main method successfully.
      'click .display'        :  'disp', // This is dynamic button generated with class as display
    },

    getAction: function(nodeId){ // Get Actions from NodeId and generate buttons
      $('.nodes').append("<button>" + action.Name + "</button>"); //Generate Buttons
      $(".nodes button").addClass("display");
    },

    disp: function(){
        alert("Inside Disp Function");
    },
```

On clicking `#display-nodes` the nodes are displayed as required but `.display` is not working. How do I make this button call the function?

Comment: Can you post relevant markup as well?

Comment: Is `.nodes` nested beneath the `package-template` div? Example: `<div class="package-template"><div class="nodes"><button class="display">actionName</button></div></div>`

Comment: If it is in fact nested, the button should still be added if you use `this.$('.nodes').append(...` instead of `$('.nodes').append(...`. In a Backbone view, `this.$` is a scoped jQuery object.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A Backbone view can receive events from dynamically generated DOM elements, through the `events` property, as long as the dynamically generated DOM elements are descendants of the view's `el`. The relevant code is in [delegateEvents()](http://devdocs.io/backbone/index#View-delegateEvents). It uses jQuery's [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) selector method.

The most likely reason it's not working for you is that the newly created `<button>` is not a descendant of the view's `el`. Am I right?

If this is the case and you want to keep the element outside of the view's `el`, you can remove it from your view's `events` property and delegate on another element in your view's `init` method.

Comment: @Eric - if it solved your problem and you're not waiting for further answers, you should mark as accepted answer.