# Backbone event not firing after webuipopover

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

When I click the "Add" button on [webui popover](https://github.com/sandywalker/webui-popover), then the alert does not fire. Why is the event not triggering?

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #btnAdd': function() {
            alert('Add');
        }
    },
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var template = _.template($('#myApp').html());
        this.$el.html(template);
    }
});

var myApp = new AppView({
    el: '#container'
});

$('#showPopup').webuiPopover({
    width: '500px',
    height: 'auto',
    padding: true,
    trigger: 'click',
    closeable: true,
    delay: 200,
    placement: 'right-bottom',
    animation: 'sticky',
    dismissable: true,
    onShow: function() {
        console.log(this);
    },
    content: '<div>' + 
        Popop + '<br /><input type="button" value="Add" id="btnAdd"/></div>'
});
```

---

```
<div>
    <script type="text/template" id="myApp">
        <a href="#" id="showPopup">Show popup</a>
    </script>

    <div id="container">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is not triggered because is not in template, #btnAdd Button is created dinamically by Popover, that's why the event is not binded.

Comment: `_.bindAll` is unnecessary if you're using a recent version of Backbone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

webui-popover has a [`container` option](https://github.com/sandywalker/webui-popover#default-options) where you can tell the popover to be inserted inside the Backbone view's `$el` root element.

It is inserted in the `document.body` by default.

Don't use global jQuery event listeners for this, prefer scoping to the view and whenever possible, wrapping plugins within the view itself.

Also, check how to [use the `_.template` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41148034/1218980).

```js
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // Parse the template once.
  template: _.template($('#myApp').html()),
  events: {
    'click #btnAdd': 'onClick',
  },

  render: function() {
    // It's a function, don't forget to call it: 'this.template()'
    this.$el.html(this.template());
    
    // Initialize the plugin inside the view's render
    this.$('#showPopup').webuiPopover({
      container: this.$el, // use the container option
      trigger: 'click',
      closeable: true,
      placement: 'right-bottom',
      content: '<div>test<br /><input type="button" value="Add" id="btnAdd"/></div>'
    });
    // Returning 'this' in the render function is a Backbone convention.
    return this;
  },
  onClick: function(e) {
    console.log('Add click event');
  }
});

// 'render' should be called outside the view.
var myApp = new AppView({
  el: '#container'
}).render();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webui-popover/2.1.15/jquery.webui-popover.min.css" />
<div>
  <script type="text/template" id="myApp">
    <a href="#" id="showPopup">Show popup</a>
  </script>

  <div id="container">

  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webui-popover/2.1.15/jquery.webui-popover.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The fast and EZ answer is attach event to body instead template.

```
$('body').on('click', '#btnAdd', function(){
    alert('hey buddy');
});
```

More info in: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Complex time:

- Add template for popup as template child.
- Reference that child into settings of popup.

Based on question:

[How to bind events on dynamic generated buttons in backbone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987386/how-to-bind-events-on-dynamic-generated-buttons-in-backbone)