# How to attach keypress event listeners to dynamically generated multiple input fields in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

[image]

I am trying to achieve the above screenshot using backbone.All users comes in an array together and I am looping around the array in the template.I have to capture the text entered in each input and calculate the text limit

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6988504/1110636

Comment: @Timir I am looking for array of dynamic elements and attaching events to those elements. In my example its the input field.

Comment: You will need to bind a change handler for each input, and calculate the length of text entered there. The answer linked above shows how to bind events to dynamically generated controls such as in your case.

Comment: @Timir Got it Thank you